# priority of implicit conversions

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have two classes that are interchangeable. A can be converted to B and B can be converted to A. What I would like is a way to specify that A's conversion to B is preferred, yet still be able to do things like:

```
B b = A();
B b; b = A();
```

What I'm trying to avoid is this issue:
    B b = q ? A() : B();

error: conditional expression is ambiguous; 'A' can be converted to 'B' and vice versa

I've tried a range of explicit settings, but I can't quite figure out if this is possible. I prefer to not have to call out static_cast on these.

```
struct B;
struct A {
    int a;
    A () {
    }
    A (B b);
    explicit operator B ();
};
struct B {
    int b;
    B () {
    }
    B (A a);
    explicit operator A ();
};
A::A (B b) {
}
A::operator B () {
    B b;
    return b;
}
B::B (A a) {
}
B::operator A () {
    A a;
    return a;
}
int main () {
    int q;
    A a;
    B b;
    A ab = q ? a : b;
    B b2 = a;
}
```

Comment: The solution is to do this `A ab = q ? (A)a : (A)b;`

Comment: Having two types which both know about each other and are convertible to each other tends to be a suboptimal design. Scala has some types like this, and now they recommend not to do so. It can be notably easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do this `A ab = q ? (A)a : (A)b;` this way each of them are being explicitly cast which your code tries to do this implicitly.

Comment: Actually even `A ab = q ? a : A(b);` or `A ab = q ? a : (A)b;` would work because you need to have both of the same type. But I think the question is whether it could work without all this

Comment: Yes, many different solutions would work @A.A except those which need implicit conversion

Comment: @A.A I am doing exactly as you suggested in my current implementation. But I am interested in avoiding this as you already pointed out.

Comment: Not sure you can get what you want.  The standard says " Attempts are made to form an implicit conversion sequence from an operand expression E1 of type T1 to a target type related to the type T2 of the operand expression E2" and "Using this process, it is determined whether an implicit conversion sequence can be formed from the second operand to the target type determined for the third operand, and vice versa. If **both** sequences can be formed, or **one can be formed but it is the ambiguous* conversion sequence, the program is **ill-formed**". Maybe a proxy class could help but ..?

Comment: If you remove the explicit keyword @nachum it would work

Comment: @JakeFreeman I don't think that works at all. It would give two errors then, ambiguous operator for conversion from A -> B (or B->A) and ambiguous b/c it can convert in both directions.